# 3D Object Detection-Opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have tried face recognition using OpenCV using the documentation provided on their wiki. Its working fine and it can detect multiple faces. However there is no data provided on the site regarding 3D object detection or head tracking. The links to the code and the wiki are provided below :

[Face recognition](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition)

[Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

While the wiki does provide sufficient information about face detection, as you might have found, 3D face recognition methods are not provided.

I wanted to know about projects related to 3D face recognition and tracking so that I can see the source code and try to make a project doing the same.

Comment: I am in a similar position to you, I am currently looking for a way to recognise and track 3D-objects.  If I come across anything that might help you, I will post it here.

Comment: Thanks a ton. :) You have any idea about any algorithms that can be used?

Comment: I'm afraid I am still very much a beginner in this field, but I can recommend that you look at the [SURF](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/feature_detection.html) algorithm, or at [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=G5GLIKIkd6E).  Maybe you can use a form of continuously updating template matching like he did.  [Another tutorial](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/19/quick-and-easy-head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-w-code/) that I found interesting.  Good luck!

Comment: You could always take a look at combining Voronoi tesselation and homography transforms. This method would be limited to at least having the face visible, IE no back of head recognition, but it could expand the envelope for your recognition. Do you have a particular application in mind?

Comment: Yes, something which tells me the position of the face and so I can cover it with a mask or something. I can do it using the 2D algos but I need the depth of the different parts of the face too. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might come late but willow garage has another project running called the Point Cloud Library (PCL) that is entirely focused on 3D data processing tasks. Face recognition is one of the use cases they use to advertise the project. Of course all of this is free...

http://pointclouds.org

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods. I just can point you to right direction. Face recognition examples usually provide sub-detection of eyes. So actually you know face and eyes location. In similar or other means you can also detect lips. 
Now when you have at least three points of object (face this time), you can calculate its 3D position in room using triangulation. This part of example exists in find_obj.cpp which comes as example with OpenCV. Just this example uses x points from SURF and draws rectangle based on this information. Check out also anything else with CvFindHomography.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV 2.4.2, there has been a header file for face detection **and** tracking: opencv2/contrib/detection_based_tracker.hpp

The header file defines a class called DetectionBasedTracker. The tracking mechanism it defines uses haar cascades in the background to detect objects. The tracking is much faster than the OpenCV Haar implementation (however, some have found it to be less accurate). 
I have personally found it to work very well on an android device. Some sample code implementing the face detection and tracker is found here: 
http://bytesandlogics.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/detectionbasedtracker-opencv-implementation/

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Active shapes models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_shape_model) and [Active Appearance Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model) that are for the task you are describing.
OpenCV provides you only 2D detection methods, while the methods in reference (now very popular in the field) **track a set of 3D points** distributed on a face plus a texture to describe its appearance.

The Wikipedia pages will give you some links to implementations of teh said methods.

If you want to know the 3D parameters of the head in the world coordinates (for example for gaze detection), then you should google for the keywords "3D head tracking" and "head pose estimation".